# Templated PDF output with a front end editor view

Tags: templates, pdf, adobe-indesign

Looking at various plugins, libraries to create PDF output. I'm trying to build out a application that allows admin user to upload/create their own template (complex print layouts) and a end user to create a PDF from that template with some rich editing tools. The original layouts are based in indesign/pdf. The final high res output is to printers / pdf download.

Basically a web to print project.

I'm trying to figure out to go with a commercial plugin like

- https://customerscanvas.com
- printui.com
- https://www.chili-publish.com/chili-publisher
- layoutbuddy.com

Or can someone make some recommendations or other similar projects

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Really depends on your budget, will to keep hands on stuff, etc. Most of the tools you are quoting are great. Chili Publish is great, Pressero too. I don't know PrintUI myself but the owner and it's a serious enough sign of quality to me. All of those are turn-key solutions. Once that said, if you want to build your own tool, you can have a look at PDFChip but all the wrapping development belongs to you. 
There are plenty others but those are the one i can talk about.